# I needed to access HUAWEI AppGallery Connect API and create a product through the PMS API (server API). But 403 client token authorization fail

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Recently,I needed to access HUAWEI AppGallery Connect API
and create a product through the PMS API (server API). However, when Postman
was used for basic service interconnection tests,
the error message "403 client token authorization fail" was displayed.

how can i fix it？[image: check in image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error code included in your screen captures, the error was caused by an authentication failure.

1. To solve the problem, you first need to confirm that the client ID used for applying for the token has sufficient permission.

[image]

2. HMS official document suggested that the project associated with the API client be selected as N/A. You need to create an API client and associate it with a project. E.g. An app ID in the project was 100xxx591. However, the app ID in the Postman service request was 101xxx531, which would cause the authentication failure.
   [image]
3. Also, to fix the above, you need to create an API client and selected N/A (indicating that all projects are supported), and use the client to request a token. The process should work well after this.
   [image]

In general,  if Huawei's 403 authentication failure occurs, you can verify the permission first, and then check the associated projects.
For more details about the PMS API, please refer to this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-addproduct).